# Add background image based on element width in Angular

Tags: angular

I have the following `mat-card` component in Angular that display the information of each `prof` object:

```
<mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
      <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>{{prof["fullName"].length > 15 ? prof['fullName'].slice(0, 15) + '...' : prof['fullName']}}</mat-card-title>
      </mat-card-header>
</mat-card>
```

I would like to know if I can add the profile picture from `prof['imageLink']` (which is an image link) based on the current width of the `mat-card`. So if the `mat-card` reaches a certain height, it will display the image, otherwise not.

I know the `@media` query could be helpful, but I'm displaying a list of `prof`, which has unique image link for each `prof`

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: you can show based on width or height if yes is it going to be a fixed value?

Comment: Yes if the width reaches a fixed value then show the picture from the image link

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your card inside a container div and then you can get the width of card using `offsetWidth`.

```
@ViewChild("myIdentifier") myIdentifier: ElementRef;

<div #myIdentifier>
    <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
        <mat-card-header>
            <mat-card-title>{{prof["fullName"].length > 15 ? prof['fullName'].slice(0, 15) + '...' : prof['fullName']}}
            </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <img [class.hide]="width < 500" mat-card-image [src]="prof.imageLink" alt="Photo of a Shiba Inu">
   </mat-card>
</div>
```

You need to use `ngAfterViewInit` event to get the width as only after view is rendered you can get the exact width.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.width = this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }
```

Then based on your predefined width you can show hide the profile picture.

```
<img [class.hide]="width < 500" mat-card-image [src]="prof.imageLink"/>
```

As we updating the view after view initializated. we will get an error *"Expression ___ has changed after it was checked*".

To get rid of that error we need to manually invoke change detection.

```
this.cdr.detectChanges();
```

**Edit1:** Handle page resize.

If you want to make this responsive(on page resize) you need to detect/bind browser resize event and update the width property in that and it will work.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.resizeObservable$ = fromEvent(window, "resize");
    this.resizeSubscription$ = this.resizeObservable$.subscribe(evt => {
        this.width = this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    });
}
```

Make sure to destory the subscription in component onDestroy method.

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.resizeSubscription$.unsubscribe()
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kycsrj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcard-overview-example.ts) updated with latest code changes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this only works when I reload the webpage, is there anyway that I can make it work when I resize the webpage? Like I have a sidebar component, when opening, it will decrease the width of the mat-card.

Comment: I tried with this code: ` toggleSideNav() {
    this.opened = !this.opened;
    this.width = this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    console.log(this.width);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }`

But somehow it always console log out the previous value (value before opening, which is bigger), not the current value of the width,